# Unable to connect to a Oracle db from Linux machine in java

Tags: java, linux, oracle

I have registered a Linux machine as runner in my gitlab and tried to execute my scripts there.

While executing I got an error for database connection

```
Issue : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

When I connect from my local machine (Windows 7 & 10) it is working fine.

Attempts:

- Tried to connect using jtds but I'm getting some other unknown issue.
- Checked few other answers and they have provided that it could be because of firewall enabled but since we did not have full access to that db server , I could not disable and check.(Could this be the issue?)

My Connection code :

```
ConURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ConstructSQLConnectionURL(host,sid,port);
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConURL, dbUserName, dbPassword);
```

I am stuck with this issue and blocked from executing pipeline.
Can anyone let me know what could be the possible reason for this and help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a network connectivity issue. I'd start with local firewalls on each system. Can you ping the database from the client? If not, look for network routing or firewall blockers. Also look at host-based firewalls, or confirm with the DBA whether there is something like valid node checking in place to limit database clients.